# GraphQL Array Error - "One of the provided types for building the Schema is missing a name"

Tags: graphql

I'm getting an error in my graphql resolvers file and it appears to be caused when I add the [ GraphQLID ]. Is this the correct way to add an array of GraphQLID's as I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
const tvshowArgs = {
  name: { type: GraphQLString },
  composers: { type: [ GraphQLID ] },
}
const Mutation = {
  addTvShow: {
    type: TvShowType,
    args: {
      ...tvshowArgs
    },
    resolve: async (parent, args, ctx) => {
      const { user_id } = ctx.me

      const doesExist = await TvShow.find({ tmdbId: args.tmdbId })

      if (doesExist.length > 0) {
        throw new GraphQLError('This TV Show already exists')
      }

      const tvshow = new TvShow({
        name: args.name,
        composers: args.composers,
      })
      return tvshow.save()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to do `type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID)`?

Comment: Ah completely forgot about GraphQLList, thanks heaps